# NGINX error when deploying static website with Concourse CI

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry, concourse

I encounter an error when I try to deploy a static website to Pivotal Web Services with Concourse CI. I want to push a static website using the *static_buildpack*. The *index.html* is placed in the root folder. When I push the code from the command line directly to Pivotal Web Services using the *cf push* command everything works fine.
When I use the concourse pipeline the build is terminated successfully however I get an error when accessing the website. I get an **nginx 403 Forbidden** error when trying to access the website. I tried the following manifest with the following pipeline (see below). When using Concourse CI the container is created successfully, the buildpack is used, nginx is installed and the droplet is uploaded. The app itself starts successfully.
The Cloud Foundry Logs show the following error:
`2017/09/05 08:42:54 [error] 70#0: *3 directory index of "/home/vcap/app/public/" is forbidden, client: <ip>, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "agencydemo.cfapps.io"`

manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: agencyDemo
  memory: 64M
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
  host: agencyDemo
```

pipeline.yml

```
resources:
- name: app_sources
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/smichard/CloudFoundryDemo
    branch: master

- name: staging_CloudFoundry
  type: cf
  source:
    api: {{pws_api}}
    username: {{pws_user}}
    password: {{pws_password}}
    organization: {{pws_org}}
    space: {{pws_space}}
    skip_cert_check: false

jobs:
- name: deploy-website
  public: true
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: app_sources
    trigger: true
  - put: staging_CloudFoundry
    params:
        manifest: app_sources/manifest.yml
```

The source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/smichard/CloudFoundryDemo)

Comment: I would suggest that you `cf ssh` to your app instance after it's been deployed on PWS and look around.  a.) make sure your files have been uploaded b.) that they're in the expected location i.e. the `public/` directory and c.) verify the nginx config that's in place.  It kind of looks like the files are not there or not in the right path.  Nginx is saying it's not allowed to give you the directory index, which I believe would happen when there is no index.html file and is expected (directory index disabled by default).

Answer (score 1):

nginx 403 Forbidden happens mainly when index.html is not found. suggested steps

1. Check your buildpack  (which now is updated as buildpacks in manifest file)
2. check command or dist folder

cf push  -p ./dist/ -f manifest-{your_envireonment}.yml --no-start (if your index.html is directly under dist folder )

or

cf push  -p ./dist/{your_app_name} -f manifest-{your_envireonment}.yml --no-start (if your index.html is under dist/{your_app_name} folder )

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to fix the `path`-attribute in your `manifest.yml` as follows:

```
---
applications:
- name: agencyDemo
  memory: 64M
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
  host: agencyDemo
  path: ./dist/your-app-name
```

[Docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#path)

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that `index.html` and other angular static files are directly present inside `public/` folder and not in something like `public/your-app-name/`